# Fail on Changing the window.onresize after the page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, window-resize, onresize

I have a function name `onresizeWindow()` and `onresizeWindow2()` that i put in the head of my page to change the height of a div .

```
function onResizeWindow() {
        if (window.innerHeight && document.getElementById("divListItem"))
            document.getElementById("divListItem").style.height = window.innerHeight - 135;
        else if (document.getElementById("divListItem"))
            document.getElementById("divListItem").style.height = document.body.clientHeight - 135;
    }
function onResizeWindow2() {
        if (window.innerHeight && document.getElementById("divListItem"))
            document.getElementById("divListItem").style.height = window.innerHeight - 275;
        else if (document.getElementById("divListItem"))
            document.getElementById("divListItem").style.height = document.body.clientHeight - 275;
        }
}
```

Then in the footer of my page I put this

```
window.onresize = onResizeWindow;
onResizeWindow();
```

When user click a button, i put this code

```
function showDiv(){
        var tr = document.getElementById('tdSearch');               
        if (tr.style.display =="table-row"){
            tr.style.display = "none"; 
            window.onresize= null;
            window.onresize= onResizeWindow();
            onResizeWindow();
        }else{
            tr.style.display = "table-row";
            window.onresize= null;
            window.onresize= onResizeWindow2();
            onResizeWindow2();
        }
}
```

The problem is after clicking the button, page onresize function of the page doesn't work anymore. How to fix it?

Comment: Why did you decide to add `()` to the assignments, yet you didn't at first? Use `window.onresize= onResizeWindow2;`, for example

Comment: thanks for the answer...but i just realize..im so stupid... it should not be like that... window.onresize= onResizeWindow(); should be window.onresize= onResizeWindow; and window.onresize= onResizeWindow2(); should be window.onresize= onResizeWindow2;

Comment: I remove the brackets and that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like your original assignment, you shouldn't use `()`. Use:

```
window.onresize = onResizeWindow;
// and
window.onresize = onResizeWindow2;
```

Adding the `()` immediately calls the functions and assigns their return value to the `onresize` property. These functions return nothing, so `undefined` is the returned value, meaning nothing runs when the window is resized.

Comment: @user2495615 Don't feel stupid. It was a small mistake that many people make. Often you just need another set of eyes, and that's what StackOverflow is for. I'm glad you got the code fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `window.onresize= onResizeWindow();`, you're effectively setting `window.onresize` to `undefined`, since you are running onResizeWindow and setting onresize to the return value.

Just remove the parentheses.

```
function showDiv() {
        var tr = document.getElementById('tdSearch');               
        if (tr.style.display === "table-row") {
            tr.style.display = "none";
            window.onresize = onResizeWindow;
            onResizeWindow();
        } else {
            tr.style.display = "table-row";
            window.onresize = onResizeWindow2;
            onResizeWindow2();
        }
}
```